# Define overloaded casting operator for two classes with circular dependency between them

Tags: c++, casting, operator-overloading

I have two classes `String` And `Integer`.
I want the `String` to be able to cast to an `Integer` and `Integer` to `String`.
The way I implemented it is as follows using operator overloading (notice that the `Integer` class is template based)

```
#include <string>

class Integer; // forward declaration but doesnt fix the compiler error

class String {
public:
    operator Integer() {                                                
        try {                                               
            return std::stoi(s);
        catch(std::invalid_argument ex) {                                           

        }                                               
    }
    std::wstring s;
};

template<class T>
    class intTypeImpl {
    T value;
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    intTypeImpl() :value() {}
    intTypeImpl(T v) :value(v) {}
    operator T() const {return value;}

    operator String() {         
        return std::to_wstring(value);                                      
    }
};

typedef intTypeImpl<int> Integer;
```

The compiler is issuing

> error C2027: use of undefined type 'Integer'

so the forward declaration is of no use.
How should I implement this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: forward declare string and implement Integer before string. Also why is intTypeImpl required to be templated?

Comment: if i put the intTypeImpl  first and forward declare the string and place the String after same error happens with String "error C2027: use of undefined type 'String'". also templated class is needed cos i need typedef intTypeImpl<short> and intTypeImpl<unsigned byte> types

Comment: the only way around this that I can think of is to split the code to .hpp and .cpp files, so that your headers contain declarations of classes and their member variables/functions, and then in cpp file you implement these member functions. This is I think the traditional way to break from circle recursion

Comment: The design is problematic and I would avoid it. You are going to run into too many issues if you follow this path, prefer using named functions for the conversions. For example consider that you have two `operator==` one that takes two `String` objects, the other taking two `Integer` objects and you try to compare a `String` and an `Integer` and suddenly the compiler barfs some ambiguity error...

Comment: @Indika: If I were you, I'd not catch the `std::invalid_argument` exception - if person who use your code gave invalid argument, let him know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Casting operator overloaded outside classes:

```
/* after every line of code you posted */
operator Integer(const String& str){
    return std::stoi(str.s);
}
```

## Casting c-tor in `intTypeImpl`:

```
#include <type_traits>

/* in intTypeImpl */
intTypeImpl()=default;
intTypeImpl(const intTypeImpl<T>&)=default;

intTypeTmlp(String& str){
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<T, int>,
        "String can be converted only to intTypeImpl<int>"
    );
    value=std::stoi(str.s);
}
```

Comment: thanks using c-tor instead of cast op overloading made the compiler happy :)